# How can I delete a UIImageView that I created by code?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm developing a iOs app for iPad. I would like to delete two objects (UIImage and UIImageView) that are created by code.

```
UIImage *imatgetemporal = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imatgetemporal];
```

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to remove the UIImage. You can remove the imageView like this [img removeFromSuperView]; [img release];

Comment: But the problem is that I'm recurring to the imagesview size, so if I don't delete it, when I change the image inside, it keeps the old image size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to delete things is to set them to `nil`. So you might have

```
img = nil;
```

You could keep the UIImageView alive but simply change out the image it displays by updating the `image` property of the UIImageView with a new image.

When you remove an item from the superview you are simply taking it off of the screen. It is still in memory.

Something that is unclear to me from your code is how you are persisting the objects. I assume that you are setting the `UIImageView` to a property somewhere. if that's the case, I would expect that your code above looks like (I am using a property called mainImageView for an example)

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imatgetemporal];
[self setMainImageView:img];
```

or you could even reuse the `UIImageView` property you have each time (this assumes you only want to display one image at a time) and just replace the image with a new one.

```
UIImage *imatgetemporal = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

[[self mainImageView] setImage:imatgetemporal];
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a imagepickerview and every time I touch an image I create a uiimage with what you selected and an imageview with the image. So before that, I've to clean the objects because this action is called severa times.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on what I think you are saying. If you have a UIImageView property then you can just replace it with a new image each time.

Comment: So its better to create once and then rewrite on it, that create avery time you want to display and image. True?

Comment: I usually create the UIImageView one time and then just change its image property. I would only create multiple UIImageViews if I wanted to show multiple images on the screen at the same time. A neat feature of UIImageViews is that you can assign them an array of UIImages and then it will animate. Read the documentation about 'animationImages' for UIImageView for lots of interesting things.